# Json schema validation with if else condition and rest assured

Tags: json, jsonschema, rest-assured

I'm struggling with the json validation against json schema and Rest Assured. The thing is that I need to use if else condition in it and for some reason my test are always green even I'm defining wrong condition. I used json-schema 7 which should support if else but when I'm defining false condition and my test should be failed with some error but its actually passed according to that I can say that its not checking that condition at all.
Here is my json:

```
{
    "courses": [{
        "position": "1",
        "previous_course_rank": "",
        "location": "Weston, FL",
        "established": "",
        "course_name": "Weston Hills - Tour Course",
        "course_id": "056",
        "holes": [{
            "hole": "1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is my json schema validation with the if else condition in it.
As you can see from if else condition I'm expecting to have established empty string only with course_id: 056 but in other cases I'm expecting established to be year like 2022. The thing is when I'm trying to test false condition and putting in if year pattern [0-9{4} its green too and I can't understand why.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "courses"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "courses": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "position",
          "previous_course_rank",
          "location",
          "established",
          "course_name",
          "course_id",
          "holes"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "position": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "previous_course_rank": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "course_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "course_id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "holes": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "required": [
                "hole"
              ],
              "properties": {
                "hole": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "course_id": {
              "const": "056"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "established": {
              "pattern": "^$"
            }
          }
        },
        "else": {
          "properties": {
            "established": {
              "pattern": "^[0-9]{4}$"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my method of checking json against json schema

```
ValidatableResponse response = getResponse(feedUrl);

response
.body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(pathToSchema))
.assertThat();
```

Comment: Try `if: false, then: false` as your schema. That should fail validation. Otherwise, what you're using doesn't support `if/then/else` keywords (found in draft-07 and up).

Answer (score 2):

`"pattern": ""` means "match everything". Perhaps you meant `"const": ""`?

Also, if you want to match a four digit number exactly, without permitting any leading or trailing characters, you need to explicitly anchor the pattern: `"pattern": "^[0-9]{4}$"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my schema to be failed in anyway but its passed again. I put that "pattern": "^[0-9]{4}$" for both conditions and I have empty string and its passed again.

Comment: Based on your updated question, everything works as you're expecting it to when I test the schema and instance data. See: https://jsonschema.dev/s/vPtHM

Comment: If something is not working as you expect, you need to explain in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below schema: [json schema validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/2guGAbU5)

I'm using property type for validation for `if` condition I'm setting type as `string` with `maxLength` is zero and for `else` I'm setting `type` as `number` with `minimum` and `maximum` properties, You can updated these based on your requirement

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "courses"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "courses": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "position",
                    "previous_course_rank",
                    "location",
                    "established",
                    "course_name",
                    "course_id",
                    "holes"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "position": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "previous_course_rank": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "course_name": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "course_id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "holes": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": [
                                "hole"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "hole": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "if": {
                    "properties": {
                        "course_id": {
                            "const": "056"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "then": {
                    "properties": {
                        "established": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "maxLength": 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                "else": {
                    "properties": {
                        "established": {
                            "type": "number",
                            "minimum": 1900,
                            "maximum": 3000
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the root cause of the issue is that restassured by default is using draft-03 schema and they can't support version draft-06 and draft-07.

This is what we have in case if you want to upgrade that draft version.
So there is no way to use if else condition with rest-assured in my understanding.

```
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.newBuilder()
        .setValidationConfiguration(
                ValidationConfiguration.newBuilder()
                        .setDefaultVersion(SchemaVersion.DRAFTV3)
                        .freeze()).freeze();
```

So my solution is to use everit json schema
https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema

```
Schema schema = getSchema(schemaPath);

SoftAssertions softAssertions = new SoftAssertions();
try {
    schema.validate(new JSONObject(getResponseAsString(jsonEndPointUrl)));
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    collectAllAssertions(softAssertions, e);
}

softAssertions.assertAll();
```

Maybe you are able to use draft-06 and draft-07 with rest-assured
Feel free to post your solution.